# Build Errors with umbraco 7.4 visual studio 2013,

Tags: umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco. I am trying to build the website using it. Due to some issues i deleted the Umbraco project that i have created. I had back up so i copy and pasted it in visual studio project folder and tried to run. Before execution it show build error which are out of my knowledge.

> The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already contains a definition for
>   'ModelTypeAlias'  C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  30  27  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 5   The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already contains a definition for
>   'ModelItemType'   C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  31  38  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 6   Type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already defines a member called 'Home' with the same parameter
>   types C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\M
>       Error 7   Type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already defines a member called 'GetModelContentType' with the same parameter
>   types C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  39  42  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 8   Type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already defines a member called 'GetModelPropertyType' with the same parameter
>   types C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  45  39  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 9   The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already contains a definition for 'BodyText' C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  54  22  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 10  The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already contains a definition for
>   'CarouselImages'  C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  63  17  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 11  The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already contains a definition for
>   'FooterText'  C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  72  17  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 12  The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Home' already contains a definition for
>   'PageTitle'   C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  81  17  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 13  The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Glimpses' already contains a definition for
>   'ModelTypeAlias'  C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\MyUmbracoApp\App_Data\Models\models.generated.cs  92  27  MyUmbracoApp
>       Error 14  The type 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Glimpses' already contains a definition for 'ModelItemType'

Comment: Can you clear the `App_Data` Models folder? And then rebuild your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. finally i m not getting any errors and my project is running finely.

Comment: I will place it as an answer so you can mark this as the solution. In this way others with the same issue can see this solution.

Answer (score 7):

In your project you have a folder called `App_Data`. In this folder you will find a `Models` folder which contains all the generated .cs class files of your Umbraco project.

You can delete this folder and then rebuild the application. During the rebuild your class files will be re-generated and placed in the `App_Data/Models` folder.

Comment: When your project is in version control you could also check if there aren't any conflicts in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Delete didn't work for me and created different errors.

What worked for me was when I excluded the App_Data\Models folder from the project (and previously had to change the App_Data folder properties from readonly).

The project rebuilt immediately.